# Assembly: Creating an array of linked nodes

Tags: arrays, assembly, linked-list

Firstly, if this question is inappropriate because I am not providing any code or not doing any thinking on my own, I apologize, and I will delete this question.

For an assignment, we are required to create an array of nodes to simulate a linked list. Each node has an integer value and a pointer to the next node in the list. Here is my `.DATA` section

```
.DATA
linked_list DWORD 5 DUP (?) ;We are allowed to assume the linked list will have 5 items
linked_node STRUCT
    value BYTE  ?
    next BYTE ?
linked_node ENDS
```

I am unsure if I am defining my `STRUCT` correctly, as I am unsure of what the type of `next` should be. Also, I am confused as how to approach this problem. To insert a node into `linked_list` I should be able to write `mov [esi+TYPE linked_list*ecx]`, correct? Of course, I'd need to `inc ecx` every time. What I'm confused about is how to do `mov linked_node.next, "pointer to next node"` Is there some sort of operator that would allow me to set the pointer to the next index in the array equal to a `linked_node.next` ? Or am I thinking about this incorrectly? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In a 32 bit environment pointers are 32 bit, that is `DWORD` size. You load them as any other `DWORD`. Not sure what you want to use `ecx` for, you can't index a linked list (unless you know it's stored as an array, but that's kinda beside the point). If you want actual syntax help, specify which assembler you are using.

Comment: I apologize if it wasn't clear enough, but I did state that it would be an array of nodes. Would that not allow me to index through the array?

Comment: Yes, it was clear that you'd store it in an array, but I assume you are not expected to use that knowledge and instead utilize the normal linked list mechanism (ie. traversing the `next` links). Even if the nodes are in an array, they might not be in order, or maybe not all slots are valid.

Comment: I see...so I would just do `mov linked_node.next, PTR linked_list`? Sorry, I am completely new to Assembly(learning it for only about 2 weeks or so).

Comment: To add a node, you'd set the `next` link to the next available storage, which in your case is indeed the indexed array slot. What I meant was that for traversing the list, you shouldn't index (probably - maybe you are allowed to).

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying now. If I'm setting `next` equal to the next storage slot, there would be no need for me to index, correct? I would be able to just say `linked_node.next` continuously until I reached the end of the array, yes?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea of traversing a generic linked list (where you don't know it's an array).

Comment: @MistFTW keep in mind that linked lists are *usually*, perhaps even *almost always* implemented with pointers, as Jester suggests, but they do not *have to be* implemented with pointers. They can be implemented with indexes.  So your original idea of using a byte-sized index to address nodes in that tiny array may be unorthodox, but it is not unheard of.

Comment: I think that the use of STRUCT is a bit too advanced for a beginner.  Keep in mind that your entire node is two bytes long, so it fits within a single 16-bit register, without the need for a STRUCT. Even if each member was two bytes long, your entire node would still fit inside a single 32-bit register.  Are you sure you have to use STRUCT to complete your assignment?

Comment: @MikeNakis: On a 64bit system, where pointers take 8 bytes, it could be worth storing all your nodes in a `std::vector` or something to keep node sizes smaller.  I mentioned this in my answer, so I won't go into more about a custom allocator for nodes...

Comment: @MikeNakis Yes, we are required to complete this assignment using structures.

Answer (score 1):

Think about your design in terms of a language you *are* familiar with.  Preferably C, because pointers and values in C are concepts that map directly to asm.

Let's say you want to keep track of your linked list by storing a pointer to the head element.

```
#include <stdint.h>  // for int8_t

struct node {
    int8_t next;  // array index.  More commonly, you'd use  struct node *next;
                  // negative values for .next are a sentinel, like a NULL pointer, marking the end of the list
    int8_t val;
};

struct node storage[5];  // .next field indexes into this array
uint8_t free_position = 0;  // when you need a new node, take index = free_position++;

int8_t head = -1;  // start with an empty list
```

There are tricks to reduce corner cases, like having the list head be a full node, rather than just a reference (pointer or index).  You can treat it as a first element, instead of having to check for the empty-list case everywhere.

Anyway, given a node reference `int8_t p` (where p is the standard variable name for a pointer to a list node, in linked list code), the next node is `storage[p.next]`.  The next node's `val` is `storage[p.next].val`.

Let's see what this looks like in asm.  The [NASM manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html) talks about how it's macro system can help you make code using global structs more readable, but I haven't done any macro stuff for this.  You might define macros for `NEXT` and `VAL` or something, with 0 and 1, so you can say `[storage + rdx*2 + NEXT]`.  Or even a macro that takes an argument, so you could say `[NEXT(rdx*2)]`.  If you're not careful, you could end up with code that's *more* confusing to read, though.

```
section .bss
storage: resw 5   ;; reserve 5 words of zero-initialized space
free_position: db 0   ;; uint8_t free_position = 0;


section .data
head: db -1       ;; int8_t head = -1;

section .text


; p is stored in rdx.  It's an integer index into storage
;  We'll access  storage  directly, without loading it into a register.
;  (normally you'd have it in a reg, since it would be space you got from malloc/realloc)

     ; lea rsi, [rel storage]   ;; If you want RIP-relative addressing. 
     ;; There is no [RIP+offset + scale*index] addressing mode, because global arrays are for tiny / toy programs.

    test    edx, edx
    js  .err_empty_list       ;; check for p=empty list (sign-bit means negative)

    movsx   eax, byte [storage + 2*rdx]   ;; load p.next into eax, with sign-extension
    test    eax, eax
    js  .err_empty_list       ;; check that there is a next element

    movsx   eax, byte [storage + 2*rax + 1]  ;;  load storage[p.next].val, sign extended into eax
        ;; The final +1 in the effective address is because the val byte is 2nd.
        ;; you could have used a 3rd register if you wanted to keep p.next around for future use

    ret  ;; or not, if this is just the middle of some larger function


.err_empty_list:   ; .symbol is a local symbol, doesn't have to be unique for the whole file
    ud2   ; TODO: report an error instead of running an invalid insns
```

Notice that we get away with shorter instruction encoding by sign-extending into a 32bit reg, not to the full 64bit rax.  If the value is negative, we aren't going to use `rax` as part of an address.  We're just using `movsx` as a way to zero-out the rest of the register, because `mov  al, [storage + 2*rdx]` would leave the upper 56 bits of `rax` with the old contents.

Another way to do this would be to `movzx  eax, byte [...] / test al, al`, because the 8-bit `test` is just as fast to encode and execute as a 32bit `test` instruction.  Also, `movzx` as a load has one cycle lower latency than `movsx`, on AMD Bulldozer-family CPUs (although they both still take an integer execution unit, unlike Intel where `movsx/zx` is handled entirely by a load port).

Either way, `movsx` or `movzx` is a good way to load 8-bit data, because you avoid problems with reading the full reg after writing a partial reg, and/or a false-dependency (on the previous contents of the upper bits of the reg, even if *you* know you already zeroed it, the CPU hardware still has to track it).  Except if you know you're not optimizing for Intel pre-Haswell, then you don't have to worry about partial-register writes.  Haswell does dual-bookkeeping or something to avoid extra uops to merge the partial value with the old full value when reading.  AMD CPUs, P4, and Silvermont don't track partial-regs separately from the full-reg, so all you have to worry about is the false dependency.

---

Also note that you can load the `next` and `val` packed together, like

```
.search_loop:
    movzx    eax,  word [storage + rdx*2]   ; next in al,  val in ah
    test     ah, ah
    jz   .found_a_zero_val
    movzx    edx, al        ; use .next for the next iteration
    test     al, al
    jns   .search_loop

    ;; if we get here, we didn't find a zero val
    ret

.found_a_zero_val:
    ;; do something with the element referred to by `rdx`
```

Notice how we have to use `movzx` anyway, because all the registers in an effective address have to be the same size.  (So `word [storage + al*2]` doesn't work.)

This is probably more useful going the other way, to store both fields of a node with a single store, like `mov [storage + rdx*2], ax` or something, after getting `next` into `al`, and `val` into `ah`, probably from separate sources.  (This is a case where you might want to use a regular byte load, instead of a movzx, if you don't already have it in another register).  This isn't a big deal: don't make your code hard to read or more complex just to avoid doing two byte-stores.  At least, not until you find out that store-port uops are the bottleneck in some loop.

---

Using an index into an array, instead of a pointer, can save a lot of space, esp. on 64bit systems where pointers take 8 bytes.  If you don't need to free individual nodes (i.e. data structure only ever grows, or is deleted all at once when it is deleted), then an allocator for new nodes is trivial: just keep sticking them at the end of the array, and `realloc(3)`.  Or use a c++ `std::vector`.

---

With those building blocks, you should be all set to implement the usual linked list algos.  Just store bytes with `mov [storage + rdx*2], al` or whatever.

If you need ideas on how to implement linked lists with clean algos that handle all the special-cases with as few branches as possible, have a look at [this Codereview question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/104940/50567).  It's for Java, but my answer is very C-style.  The other answers have some nice tricks, too, some of which I borrowed for my answer.  (e.g. using a dummy node avoids branching to handle the insertion-as-a-new-head special case).